# How to set pass some document field values as a parameter for subquery solr

Tags: solr

trying to set value from parent(ParentId) document to subquery field(ChildId) like below.

?fl=*,emp:[subquery]&emp.rows=2&emp.fl=*&emp.q={!terms f=ChildId v=$row.ParentId}
But didnt get the result.

but when I hard code the value like below its working.
?fl=*,emp:[subquery]&emp.rows=2&emp.fl=*&emp.q=ChildId:123

Am i missing something?

using nested entity with SQL query to index.

```
   <entity name="parent" query="select * from table where condition">
  <field column="parentId"/>
  <entity name="child" query="select 8 from table where 
  childId=${parent.id}"> 
 <field column="childId"/>
 </entity>
</entity>`
```

Comment: Hello, could you please add some examples of data -> and how is parent linked with the child?

Comment: added data-config details on how i index the data.